# Share a variable across CPU and GPU-CUDA

Tags: cuda

I need to access a variable on CPU and CUDA GPU. Currently, I am transferring that variable to CPU after kernel finishes, but it is turning out to be bottleneck in my application. Is there any way faster way to access a variable on CPU after GPU finishes execution? Can pinned memory help me here?

Comment: Pinned memory should help.

Comment: You might also want to investigate zero copy memory.

Comment: zero copy memory is giving even bad performance..by application time increased by 100ms...

Comment: Does setting a pinned memory allocated variable internally calls cudaMemset?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if you should use pinned memory, therefore I assume that you are not using it, which also means that you are not doing asynchronous memcpy because that would require pinned memory.

So to answer your question: yes, you should use pinned memory and use streams and async memory transfer functions to get the result as fast as possible.

Please see also http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution and http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#page-locked-host-memory